# Hazelcast EntryListener: Why is set() returning and oldValue different than null?

Tags: hazelcast

I have joined a new project about a year ago and I have started to do some minor tasks with Hazelcast, including the creation of MapStores and EntryListeners for our IMaps.

Since the beginning that I am aware of the difference between using `set()` and `put()`, with the ladder carrying the weight of deserializing and returning the old value. That is why I would use `put` when we needed to access the oldValue in the EntryListeners and use `set` otherwise.

However, for the past weeks, my team started to report occurrences where map insertions done with `set()` would trigger  the `cEntryUpdated` with a populated `oldValue`, which "breaks" some of our current logic.

Now I don't know if this was some recent change released by Hazelcast (we are currently using version `3.12.1`) or if I'm just doing something wrong from the beginning. Shouldn't I expect that `set` would *always* trigger the listener with an empty `oldValue`?

Answer (score 0):

There is always an old value, but the writer and listener are independently configurable for whether they receive it.

On map, the writer can use `V Map.put(K,V)` to receive the old value.
Or, the writer can use `void Map.put(K,V)` to not receive the old value.

On a listener, use the `include-value=true` to receive the old and new values, and `include-value=false` not to. On an insert, the old value will be null. On a delete, the new value will be null.